# How to access json array elements (keys) , values in json nested dictionary type using postgresql?

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, nested-json

I have a nested structure json .
How to extract the specific elements(keys)  and values?

How to access " sky: selling":"1"
Or "U1":"0000" ?
I tried json_object_keys and json_array_elements for extracting the array .
But I don't know exactly how to do this query.
Example code:

Table- record and column name : report

```
{

  "PIname": {

    "n1": "x1",

                "n2": "x2",

                "params": {

                "S1": {

        "code1": "y1",

        "Code2": "y2",

      },

      "id": "2d",

      "Dest": {

        "Code3": "mi"

      }

    },

                "PIDataArea": {

                "m1": null,

      "PInven": {

        "head": {

          "Code4": "Increase",

          "line": "2020-01"

        },

                                "PILine": [

          {

            "u1": "0000",

            "u2": "0",

            "u3": "1",

            "modes": {

              "@cID": "Sng",

              "#txt": "12.21"

            }                                               },
                                               {
            "Qualify": ".0001",

            "QOrder": "1",

            "UPriceAmt": {

              "@cID": "sng",

              "#txt": "13"                                              },

            "sky:Qa": ".000",

            "sky:Partcode": {

              "@c1ID": "a"   

            },

            "sky:SCode": "Ni",

            "sky:PItem": {

              "sky:ID": "h"   

            },

            "sky:Forest": {

              "sky:q1": [

                {

                  "sky:selling": "1"
                }

                {

                  "sky:selling": "0"  

                }
         ]

          }                                            }                                                }}  }}
```

I tried lot ,one example query here like,
Select * from record r
Where exists( select report->'sky: selling' from json_each(r.report) b where b.value->>'sky:selling' Ilike '0');

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `json_path_query` or `jsonb_path_query` function. Example to extract the element with key = "sky:selling" :

```
json_path_query(r.report, $.** ? (@.key == 'sky:selling'))
```